# How to find time average of two datetime rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with datatime and person identity in which I wanted to find difference between time for each day and find the average in SQL.

The input table,

```
    +---------------------+----------+--------+
    |      Datetime       | Identity |  Type  |
    +---------------------+----------+--------+
    | 28/08/2019 4:00:00  | ABC      | Entry  |
    | 28/08/2019 14:00:00 | ABC      | Exit   |
    | 29/08/2019 6:00:00  | ABC      | Entry  |
    | 29/08/2019 6:10:00  | ABC      | Exit   |
    | 30/08/2019 8:00:00  | ABC      | Entry  |
    | 30/08/2019 17:00:00 | ABC      | Exit   |
    +---------------------+----------+--------+
```

Is it possible to create another table with the below data in SQL?

```
    +------------+----------+-----------+
    |    Date    | Identity | Time(Min) |  
    +------------+----------+-----------+
    | 28/08/2019 | ABC      |       600 |  
    | 29/08/2019 | ABC      |        10 |  
    | 30/08/2019 | ABC      |       540 |  
    +------------+----------+-----------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "SQL" is a just a language, not an actual product.  What _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.)?

Comment: Which SQL database are you using? What type is your Datetime column? Will there always be two times per day?

Comment: Yes there are always two times per day. I am using the SQL Server Management Studio V18.2

Comment: @harishmd: is there any possibility that we have more then 2 records per day?

Comment: maybe for rare cases of observations it has only one record, but it has 2 records each day for almost 95% of the data @DarkRob

Comment: I mean that for one date there is only one entry and exit, multiple entries are not allowed, and please be sure 100%, otherwise your query will fail for some case which is not handled.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - it'll work for mysql

```
select cast(datetime as date), 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,min(case when Type='Entry' then datetime end),
       max(case when Type='Exit' then datetime end))
from tablename
group by cast(datetime as date)
```

OR for sql server -

```
select cast(datetime as date), 
           datediff(mi,min(case when Type='Entry' then datetime end),
           max(case when Type='Exit' then datetime end))
    from tablename
    group by cast(datetime as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should give you what you need, in SQL Server:

```
select cast([datetime] as date) as [Date]
    , [Identity]
    , datediff(minute, min([datetime]), max([datetime])) as [Time(Min)]
from table_name
group by cast([datetime] as date)
    , [Identity]
```